# Recording an array of specific size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am caching 20 max records for entered values.
here is the code

```
NSMutableArray *startingArray = [[defaults objectForKey:@"startingTextArray"] mutableCopy];

if (startingArray == nil)
startingArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

if (![startingArray containsObject:self.starting.text])
[startingArray addObject:self.starting.text];

[defaults setObject:startingArray forKey:@"startingTextArray"];
```

THe problem is, how can I make it fix for 20 values only? e.g if 20 spaces are filled then the next entry setObject adds at first location and remove the very first entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check whether you're at your 20th object and if you are start replacing the object at index 0

```
 NSMutableArray *startingArray = [[defaults objectForKey:@"startingTextArray"] mutableCopy];
    if (startingArray == nil)
        startingArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];


if (![startingArray containsObject:self.starting.text] && (startingArray.count +1) <= 20)
     [startingArray addObject:self.starting.text];
else {
     [startingArray insertObject:obj atIndex:0];
     [startingArray removeObjectAtIndex:(startingArray.count - 1)];
}


[defaults setObject:startingArray forKey:@"startingTextArray"];
```

Comment: if i replace the object at 0 then it won't act like LIFO. i wAnt the array to act like that

Answer (score 0):

use some counter and modulo

example:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++)
    array[i % 20] = @(i);
```

prints:

40,
    41,
    22,
    23,
    24,
    25,
    26,
    27,
    28,
    29,
    30,
    31,
    32,
    33,
    34,
    35,
    36,
    37,
    38,
    39